# How to write iOS Unit Testing in SwiftUI when switching from background thread to main thread

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xctest

Once my background operation completed i need to call handleError function. Since isToast, errorMessage are published variables i need to put in main thread. I wrote a func for test test__Failure() but before simulateRequestFailure complete, this line is executed in function  XCTAssertTrue(self.viewModel.isToast). How to put wait, delay for few seconds

```
@Published var isToast: Bool = false
@Published var eMessage: String = ""
```

```
func handleError() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.isToast = true
            self.eMessage = “Test message”
        }
    }
```

```
func test__Failure() {
         // Some simulate response which call handleError    
         self.simulateRequestFailure()
        XCTAssertTrue(self.vm.isToast)

    }
```

Comment: How do you come to know when the request got failed in your code means there is no call back inside **test_Failure** method? Please update your code if possible, @Neha Pant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delay verification and check it on main thread as well, something like this:

```
let expectation = XCTestExpectation()
self.simulateRequestFailure()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1)) {
    XCTAssertTrue(self.vm.isToast)
    expectation.fulfill()
}
wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10.0)
```

What this does:

- `Expectation` allows to synchronize test thread with `main` thread. I.e. test will not complete until either `expectation.fulfill()` happens, or 10 seconds expire (you can of course change 10 sec to whatever)
- `simulateRequestFailure()` runs on main thread asynchronously, so we let it run and schedule verification on the same thread, but a bit delayed (by 1 sec, but you can change it to whatever makes sense)

Comment: Hi Kiril, It works for me Thanks alot :) , 1 question do we require to add "wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10.0)" ?

Comment: yes, you need that to make sure your test doesn't complete prematurely (it ensures that code running on main thread completes first). You can of course change timeout to lesser number (although that timeout only matters if expectation is not satisfied)