# Can the "main thread" be used from XCTestCase?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

When doing unit tests in XCode I find that I cannot run code on the main thread from another thread.  What is wrong with this code?  The variable `run` is not reset

```
import XCTest
class TestMainThread: XCTestCase {
    override func setUpWithError() throws {
    }
    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
    }
    
    func testMain() throws {
        var run = true
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // return to the main thread so can interact with UI
            run = false
        }
        while run {
            print("Running")
            usleep(1000000)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your testMain() method already runs on the main thread.

Comment: Yes you can use main queue, but the use of `while` loop is incompatible, as discussed in [answer to your prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65573193/1271826). Use expectations if you want to wait for something dispatched back to the main queue. I’m unclear why you insist on the `while` loop pattern. At best, it’s inefficient, and at worst, it introduces deadlock risk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write iOS Unit Testing in SwiftUI when switching from background thread to main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61366006/how-to-write-ios-unit-testing-in-swiftui-when-switching-from-background-thread-t)

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use DispatchQueue in XCTest. However, you can use it in the class that you test and change the value over there.

```
func operationToBeTested(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    ...
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
            completion()
        }
}

func test_operationToBeTested() {
    let exp = expectation(description: "asyncTest")
    XCTAssertFalse(mockView.isPrepareUICalled)
    mockClass.operationToBeTested {
        exp.fulfill()
        XCTAssertTrue(...)
    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 5)
}
```

p.s.: as @Rob explained in the comments, we use DispatchQueue in XCTests when we write "expectation".

Comment: What do mean by “You cannot use `DispatchQueue` in XCTest”? You can. You simply need to avoid writing tests that deadlock (e.g. by using expectations).

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong; you cannot write DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //
        } 
in test function, you need to write "expectation" instead.

Comment: Sure, whenever you’re testing something asynchronous, you would use an expectation. So, you _can_ use a `DispatchQueue` in a test, but to wait for the completion, one would use it conjunction with an expectation. In short, I’m agreeing that one would use expectations, but it’s misleading or confusing to imply that one couldn’t use GCD in conjunction with expectations. That’s the whole reason why we even have expectations, to handle asynchronous things (like `DispatchQueue`) in tests.

Comment: Please take down the statement that GCD cannot be used in XCTest its quite misleading. Expectations and GCD are two separate things.